# setcookie in PHP works only on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, setcookie

I've developed a web app, using cookie. If I set a cookie in localhost with php it works, but if I move the project to a domain (app.segresta.it) cookie stop working. 
I have done a couple of test and I discovered that if I use javascript, cookie are precisely setted.

```
setcookie("user", id_user);
```

Localhost are Linux Ubuntu 15.10.
Domain is Linux.

Comment: Error reporting? HTTP response inspection (curl/wget etc)? What's in the browser cookie store?

Comment: Do you have access to the machine where it is hosted. If you do can you try to load it there trough localhost and check if you still have cookies. If it works there it could be something with firewall.

Comment: A cookie is set for a specific domain, if you change domains/subdomains, it's not valid there anymore,

Comment: I've set error_reporting(E_ALL)  in PHP but anything are write in the Page. I've also set time e domain parameter but still not working.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the following syntax:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "example.com");
```

where "example.com" is your domain name or just "/" instead of domain name. It works for me by this way.

Comment: This is wrong - domain is not required and should be avoided for cross-site compatibility.

Comment: as I wrote, you can specify "/" instead of domain name to let it send cookie for a domain and sub domaines

Comment: Regardless, the likely issue is somewhere on the server's php.ini file if you need to explicitly specify a domain.